# Can't find the relationship between two columns of numbers. Please Help

Tags: correlation

I cannot find the relationship between these two columns...other than I know that they both increase or decrease in value at the same time. I'm not a math person, but I would appreciate any help someone might be able to give.

\begin{array} {lll}
&DATE            &COL A   &COL B\\
&12/22/2015\quad &65.9 &9.984\\
&12/21/2015 &61.58 &9.826\\
&12/18/2015 &54.76 &9.624\\
&12/17/2015 &45.53 &9.416\\
&12/16/2015 &41.81 &9.346\\
&12/15/2015 &41.18 &9.334\\
&12/14/2015 &41.25 &9.336\\
&12/11/2015 &42.66 &9.378\\
&12/10/2015 &40.12 &9.322\\
&12/9/2015 &36.77 &9.25\\
&12/8/2015 &32.17 &9.156\\
&12/7/2015 &27.93 &9.074\\
&12/4/2015 &27.1 &9.058\\
&12/3/2015 &27.14 &9.06\\
&12/2/2015 &27.75 &9.096\\
&12/1/2015 &26.9 &9.076\\
&11/30/2015 &25.16 &9.034\\
&11/27/2015 &22.05 &8.958\\
&11/25/2015 &19.26 &8.89\\
&11/24/2015 &14.85 &8.784\\
&11/23/2015 &14.28 &8.77\\
&11/20/2015 &14.36 &8.782\\
&11/19/2015 &14.37 &8.784\\
&11/18/2015 &13.36 &8.754\\
&11/17/2015 &13.47 &8.776\\
&11/16/2015 &14.34 &8.954\\
&11/13/2015 &15.69 &9.21\\
&11/12/2015 &17.4 &9.496\\
&11/11/2015 &20.15 &9.882\\
\end{array}

Comment: Spreadsheet packages have correlation and graphing functions, so I would try that to get some visual clues. I'm not sure what mathematical help you can usefully get.

Comment: sorry the cut paste came out as this awkward stream of numbers.. Another hunch I have is that Some amount is being added or subtracted from the column with the larger value numbers when the column with the smaller value numbers goes up or down.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have tried using the correl formula within Excel. i get a correlation rate of .77. but that is not helping me because i don't know what to do with the number (.77)

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20%2865.9%2C%209.984%29%2C%20%2861.58%2C%209.826%29%2C%20%2854.76%2C%209.624%29%2C%20%2845.53%2C%209.416%29%2C%20%2841.81%2C%209.346%29%2C%20%2841.18%2C%209.334%29%2C%20%2841.25%2C%209.336%29%2C%20%2842.66%2C%209.378%29%2C%20%2840.12%2C%209.322%29) may help too (first couples only...).

Comment: hi Raymond. What is alpha... is that within excel as well. What does it do?

Comment: Running a scatter plot on the data it looks like two lines that intersect at $(14.28,8.77)$.  Most of the points lie on a single, well defined, line but there are $4$ points that define a separate line namely $(14.34,8.954),(15.69.9.21),(17.4,9.496),(20.15,9.882)$.  Hard to call those outliers (too many of them and they do define a pretty clear line).

Comment: Thank you Lulu. Raymond above left a link or Alpha. I clicked on it, but am unable to interpret what I am seeing . Are you familiar with Alpha?

Comment: Sure, but Excel is fine.  Draw the scatterplot.  the strong line ($85\%$ of the data) is easily identified.  The weaker line is surprisingly clear, else I'd be inclined to identify those points as experimental error of some sort.  Hard to use statistical measures (like correlation) without some model for the data.

Comment: Thank you Lulu. I did the scatter plot. I see the outliers. fyi, the column with the smaller value numbers are based on a 5 day moving average. I noticed that the 1st four values are the outliers. Perhaps it is not until the input of the 5th day that the stronger (85% of the data) line could be formed. What I am wanting to do is to be able to derive the larger value numbers by using only the smaller value numbers. For example: I want to derive the number 65.9 from 9.984 and 61.58 from 9.826 and so on. Would you have any ideas on how to go about this.

Comment: @Torre: Alpha is an online tool that answers mathematical (and others) queries (see the [Examples](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples)). Anyway from the first nine couples it deduces that a cubic curve like $$y(x)=9.72725×10^-6\;x^3-0.00111809\,x^2+0.0607177\,x+8.05479$$ (your second column $y$ in function of the first $x$) has a fine correlation ($0.999256\approx 1$). The second line is a quadratric equation $\;y(x)= a_0 +a_1 x+ a_2x^2\,$ and the third a quartic. They are better than the usual [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Excellent continuation,

Comment: The strong line has the equation:  $y=47.723x-404.94$.

Comment: lulu, one second..

Comment: @RaymondManzoni The linear regression has $R^2~.99697$, I'd say that was pretty good already.  With only $9$ points I'd hesitate to go above linear.

Comment: Side note:  if you want a comment to be sent to someone in particular you need to include @, as in "@Torre".

Comment: @lulu Thank you. So to take an example. if I take the couple (14.85,8.78)...would it be: 8.784=47.723(14.85)-404.94?

Comment: @Torre You said you wanted to get the larger values from the smaller.  So, using the equation I wrote, we'd start with $8.78$ and compute $47.723*8.78-404.94\sim 14.259$ .  Did you want to go in the other direction?

Comment: @lulu Sorry Lulu, no you were correct...I just didn't put the values in the correct order like you did have done in your last post. I noticed that the value is slightly off 14.85 versus ~14.25..this hardly matters to me. But is there anyway of it coming out exact?

Comment: @lulu: well knowing some tools may always be useful (I used only nine values anyway). Here the result with another subset : [linear](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20%289.984%2C%2065.9%29%2C%20%289.826%2C61.58%29%2C%20%289.624%2C%2054.76%29%2C%20%289.416%2C%2045.53%29%2C%20%289.336%2C%2041.25%29%2C%20%289.25%2C%2036.77%29%2C%20%289.058%2C%2027.1%29%2C%20%289.076%2C%2026.9%29%2C%20%288.89%2C%2019.26%29%2C%20%288.782%2C%2014.36%29%2C%20%288.776%2C%2013.47%29) (the error may go to $2$)

Comment: [others](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linearfit%20%289.984%2C%2065.9%29%2C%20%289.826%2C61.58%29%2C%20%289.624%2C%2054.76%29%2C%20%289.416%2C%2045.53%29%2C%20%289.336%2C%2041.25%29%2C%20%289.25%2C%2036.77%29%2C%20%289.058%2C%2027.1%29%2C%20%289.076%2C%2026.9%29%2C%20%288.89%2C%2019.26%29%2C%20%288.782%2C%2014.36%29%2C%20%288.776%2C%2013.47%29) (only one value exceeding $0.5$) (I reverted the couples and changed the selection of couples in both cases). This gives more importance to the first large values...

Comment: @raymondmanzoni Thank you Raymond. The math you are providing I wish I could understand. Lulu provided me with the an equation that

Comment: @Torre As Raymond remarks, you can get a better fit by increasing the degree of the fitting curve.  If you go to degree $10$ you could fit any nine points exactly.  But, in experimental situations, there is always noise so there is a real danger of over-fitting.  That is, all those extra parameters just model the noise.  Your call, if you think the cubic fit is better.  Personally, I stick with simple models unless I have a clear reason to prefer something more complex.

Comment: @raymondmanzoni seems pretty good. For determining the larger value number from the smaller value number..Lulu wrote: y=47.723x-404.94 this equation is usable for me, but I thought I should ask if there is a similar easy equation for the second line..the one with these values: (14.34,8.954),(15.69.9.21),(17.4,9.496),(20.15,9.882)

Comment: Glad it helped anyway @Torre. I would not go with high polynomials either (say above $3$ since it "goes in all directions") but if your physical system could explain degree two or three I would go for it... So its all in your hands, excellent continuationn

Comment: @lulu thank you for all of your help. Is there an equation that would work as well for determining the shorter line. The one with values: (14.34,8.954),(15.69.9.21),(17.4,9.496),(20.15,9.882)?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Yes it totally helped. I would have Never...and I mean Never have been able to figure this out on my own!

Comment: The quadratic $$y(x)= 4.81097+0.381014\,x-0.00641985\,x^2$$ has a [corrleation of $0.999981$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20%2814.34%2C%208.954%29%2C%20%2815.69%2C%209.21%29%2C%20%2817.4%2C%209.496%29%2C%20%2820.15%2C%209.882%29) (nearly perfect)

Comment: The four starting points fit the line $y=6.2766x-42.014$ with $R^2\sim .995$.  Not bad.

Comment: Sorry for the competition @lulu (that was not the point really :-))

Comment: @RaymondManzoni  Oh, no need to apologize.  We see things the same way, I'm sure.  My bias (pretty strong) is always to stick with linear models absent a theoretical reason to prefer something else.  I'd feel the same way if I was seeing $R^2 \sim .8$.  But if the goal is to fit the observed sharply within the sample range then you are certainly correct that the higher degree curves fit magnificently.

Comment: I must admit that for only $4$ couples the higher polynomials don't have many merits... Cheers,

Comment: Thank you both again...I'm nicknaming you two the "Dynamic Duo" Have a great day today!

Comment: @lulu Lulu, is there a simple way that I can take any couple and determine the equation that you provided for me for deriving the larger value number from the smaller value number . I know that I have other (similar) coulples (ones that I didn't post here and that come from a completely different data set).

Comment: @Torre Not sure what you are asking.  Excel's chart functions let you do a linear regression on any data set.  That will always generate an equation of the type I wrote (you can also get higher degree fits if you prefer).  How useful these fits are depends on the data.  You should always look at a scatter plot...much better than any summary measure.

Comment: @lulu Thank you Lulu, Is the linear regression the 2  lines that were made on the scatter plot? I didn't see anything that looked similar to the equation you provided. Could you let me know how I can access that?

Comment: @lulu  These larger values and smaller values are specific to unique data sets. If I can get 5 couples I can always determine what the equation will be (both the short line made up of 4 couples OR the longer line made up of many more). Is the equation that is generated by excel allow me to fine the Y from knowing the x?

Comment: @Torre.  Here's what I did: I did a scatter plot of the raw data and saw two distinct lines.  I then separated out the data points on the two lines and separately ran regressions on each.  To your general question:  you can always compute a linear regression (even with $2$ data points) but the value of doing so depends on the data. With $2$ points there is no clear value (you can always fit a line through two points).  You should compute $R^2$ but, as I said, nothing beats just looking at the data.

Comment: @lulu Thank you lulu. When you mentioned that you did regression on each of the data points, am I correct in understanding that you "drew"  a trendline for the four couples that made up the short line and then a drew a separate trendline for the other couples? if that is correct, where then do you go in excel to see the equation? Would it actually be an equation or a excel formula?

Comment: @Torre You can read about how to do linear regressions in Excel online, eg  here https://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/res/gt/gt-reg-home.html .  Excel will display the equation for the trendline, and compute $R^2$,  if you ask it to.  All that appears under "Chart>Options"

Comment: @lulu Thank you lulu. I was able to get the equation for one of the trend lines...the larger trend line. it was: y = 0.0001x2 + 0.0076x + 8.806. my values from my couple are for x 8.784 and my value for y is 14.85. I didn't see any means of adjusting the trendline so that it fits my linear line that was drawn from the data points. I suppose if I could bend the trend line to match my data point line then the equation that is then generated for the trend line will be exact. The equation that I listed above is off considerably.

Comment: @lulu I ran it again for the longer set of couples...this time the trendline was closer. I received the following equation, but it still doesn't come very close to the Y value (not like your equation) y = 0.0218x + 8.4649R² = 0.994

Comment: @Torre  Sorry, I'm really not clear what you are asking.  It sounds like you have a precise question concerning different data than what appears above.  Hard to sort out.  Certainly, that quadratic you wrote comes no where near the extra data point.  If you have a precise question, you should post it separately.  Good luck!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Hi Raymond thank you again. If I wanted to use the Cubic equation that you gave that resulted in the .99 correlation, but wanted to verify that if I put in 9.322 (as the first part of one of my couples above) as my "x" value that I actually get out something close to 40.12 how would I do that on a hand held calculator. Could you provide the step by step process?

Comment: @Torre: Looking back at my links I notice that I reverted 'linear' and 'others' so that following the [linear link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20%289.984%2C%2065.9%29%2C%20%289.826%2C61.58%29%2C%20%289.624%2C%2054.76%29%2C%20%289.416%2C%2045.53%29%2C%20%289.336%2C%2041.25%29%2C%20%289.25%2C%2036.77%29%2C%20%289.058%2C%2027.1%29%2C%20%289.076%2C%2026.9%29%2C%20%288.89%2C%2019.26%29%2C%20%288.782%2C%2014.36%29%2C%20%288.776%2C%2013.47%29) would show you $$f(x)=14862.8-4932.17*x+541.004*x^2 -19.5755*x^3$$ For $x=9.322$ this gives $40.49$.

Comment: Of course you may experiment with alpha (change or add couples...). I found too an [online widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a96a9e81ac4bbb54f8002bb61b8d3472) by Wolfram (no I am not linked to this society...). Other widgets or tools should help you to get polynomial regression or compute it yourself using [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates). You have the right to experiment and find the most adapted method, this may even be fun!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you Raymond. That was very helpful and the site is easy to use. I had a question. I noticed that that for as many couples that I have, Alpha will give a suitable equation that allows me to calculate Y. for example, If my data set is from 10/22/2015 to 1/3/2016 it will calculate the correct equation with the highest correlation between my couples for that period. However, my ultimate aim is to be able predict Y values after 1/3/2016. Will I be able to do this? Also, I would also like to look at Y values  before 10/22/2015 by simply knowing the value of X during that period

Comment: @Torre: I don't know... We looked at column A and B and searched a relation between these columns without taking care of the date column but the values at the end (as you noticed) don't follow the same pattern : the $11/13$ we had $B=9.35$ for $A=36.77$ while the $12/8$ we had $B=9.21$ and $A=15.69$ ; the relation is clearly different! Are there only two relations depending of the date? Plenty? Is something else changing continuously or not in the background? Who knows... To see what is really going on you will need to look at the actual process going on (or data covering a larger time range)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you Raymond. Yes the first four values (in our above scenario) 11/11,11/12,11/13 and 11/16...have always been off. I'm not sure why (but im okay with it)  but it seems to be with other column A and B combinations I have put in the first 4 value don't correlate to the other line...however the the first 4 values correlate to each other. There are only two relations depending on a date. There is nothing else going on in the background. Do you think knowing this that I can predict future Y values based on knowing the x value?

Comment: @Torre: No I don't and think that you will need many more values... even if only to check that your previsions are right!

Comment: I have the access to the Pro feature in Alpha which allows to upload a file of Input data. If I want to upload my Column A and Column B (3 months worth of data). Do you know in which form Alpha likes it. So far, I've been manually typing in each couple and its tedious.

Comment: @Torre: I don't use the pro feature so that I can't be sure but data's format may be given [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RegressionCommon/ref/BestFit.html) i.e. $data = \{\{12.2, 15\}, \{12.4, 16\}\}$ (not sure of the external $\{\}$ and possibly required spaces ' ' indicated)